# Intermittent issue with GPO

Tags: windows, azure, gpo

I have applied some Group Policy Object (GPO) to a virtual machine (VM) in an Azure Virtual Desktop (AVD) environment. There would be strange occurrence where GPO residing in a different OU will be reflected with a user account.

Additional information:

- Only 1 VM is assigned to the OU.
- Admin account used to manage the GPO is used in the different OU, but the user account is used by the different OU to sign in to the VMs residing in different OU.

Comment: Based on my findings, for GPOs under "User configurations". It will still be reflected in under OUs even with the "Block inheritance" enabled and implementing the desired groups(user/computers) created in "Active directory user and computers". This is something I've yet resolved.

For GPOs with "Computer configurations" it will be applied to all computers assigned to the OU. Be sure to remove unnecessary users and add the appropriate users and computers in the security filtering of the GPO.